# how to setup minSDK, tartgetSDK, Compile using v7 Appcompat Library in android?

Tags: android, android-support-library

is this right thing to do during project creation

Min is API 7

Target is API 17

Compile is  API 18 ??

in the developer site only the min and the target is stated, should i use compile
the latest one example API 18 or 19 for compiler?

PRINT SCREEN:
http://prntscr.com/275ck0

Answer (score 0):

`targetAPI` and `compileAPI` should be latest API. ATM it's 19.

Comment: when i create a project support library its android jar is android 4.2.2 which is api lv 17? so its ok to use api18 for target and compile for my own project? the suport library that i created is 4.2.2 api 17?

Comment: It is ok. The jar listed in your screenshot is a stub anyway. there is no actual code in it. The code implementing the API is on the device. Use the newest API for compile and target, but be aware of devices running older APIs by checking for API version in sections using new API calls.

Answer (score 0):

It is right.

Use latest SDK to compile you can use new API feature like this:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void hideCalendarView(DatePicker dp) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {  
        //codes (API level >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    } else {
        //codes (API level < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    }
}
```

But use oldest SDK to compile you do not use hight API feature than compile SDK level.

Comment: i updated my question added print screen view my print screen it has my Project Support Library and my Project Supsup, the Support library is 4.2.2, then is it to use my Supsup project to min 7, target 18, compile 18?

Comment: 4.2.2 is API level 17, if you use 4.2.2 to compile your project, I suggest you set min 7, target 17, compile 17

Comment: Here is API level list:http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels